# What was the function of the pulsing light over Number 6's bed?

Tags: the-prisoner

Seen in more than one episode, there is a device over Number 6's bed. Out-of-universe, it looks like a futuristic kitchen table light. It is seen pulsing while Number 6 is apparently sleeping. What is its in-universe function? It almost seems to have different functions in different stories; does it actually do one consistent thing, and if so, what?

Comment: Its function was to provoke questions like this one.

Answer (score 4):

Its function is to put him into a deeper state of unconsciousness than ordinary sleep, so that they could manipulate him physically (move him, inject him with drugs, etc.) without any risk of his waking up.

Comment: Do you have some evidence to support this claim?

Comment: @PMar while you are correct - referencing an episode will keep the downvoters away.  From memory - Probably A,B and C did the hypnotic light fixture the most...be seeing you.